# (How) can I embed something with an iframe code into powerpoint 2010?

Tags: windows, iframe, powerpoint

I'm trying to embed something into Powerpoint 2010 that has an iframe embed code. The link I've been trying to use is http://wheeldecide.com/index.php?c1=1&c2=2&c3=3&c4=4&c5=5&c6=6&c7=7&c8=8&c9=9&c10=10&c11=11&c12=12&c13=13&c14=14&c15=15&c16=16&c17=17&c18=18&c19=19&c20=20&c21=21&c22=22&c23=23&c24=24&c25=25&c26=26&c27=27&c28=28&c29=29&c30=30&t=&remove=on&col=&time=5&width=&cols=&tcol=&x=122&y=28

---

The embed code is beneath the wheel. I'm using windows.

Comment: Please let me know if this is not on the right stack :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PowerPoint is not a browser, so it doesn't know what to do with HTML/embed code.

However, you can embed a web browser control in PPT and include your HTML in that.

Easiest way to do this is with Shyam Pillai's LiveWeb add-in for PPT:

http://skp.mvps.org/liveweb.htm#.VEaVPfmjPTo

Answer (score 5):

We built an Add-in for this called LiveSlides that works with PowerPoint 2007+ on Windows and PowerPoint 2011 and Keynote 5.2+ on Mac.

You may download the add-in for free at https://www.liveslides.com/

Comment: Just linking to your own stuff is [not a good answer](//stackoverflow.com/help/promotion). A good answer that involves an off-site resource includes the essential parts of the answer here for future users, and references the following: _What is this thing you're talking about? Where do I install it? How do I install it? How do I use this thing to solve the **exact problem** I have in my question? Are you affiliated with this thing in any way, shape, or form?_ See: [How can I link to an external resource in a community-friendly way?](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94022)

Comment: "We’re sunsetting LiveSlides on June 30, 2020. After June 30, 2020, the LiveSlides PowerPoint and Keynote integrations will no longer be supported. To continue embedding videos into your presentations, try Poll Everywhere, our parent app. Create interactive polls and add them to PowerPoint, Keynote, or Google Slides presentations in a few clicks"